# How best to create a new column for each two-column comparison using purrr?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
ABC1_old <- c(1, 5, 3, 4, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
ABC2_old <- c(4, 2, 1, 1, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
ABC1_adj <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4)
ABC2_adj <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2)

df <- data.frame(ABC1_old, ABC2_old, ABC1_adj, ABC2_adj)
```

I want to create a column that compares each pair of `ABCn_old` with its corresponding `ABCn_adj`. (So `ABC1_old` would be compared against `ABCn_adj`, etc.) The resulting column would be called `ABCn_new`. The evaluation would be that if `ABCn_old` is `NA`, fill in the blank with the corresponding value in `ABCn_adj`, otherwise use `ABCn_old`'s value. The new columns would look like this:

```
df$ABC1_new <- c(1, 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4)
df$ABC2_new <- c(4, 2, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2)
```

I know a simple `mutate` could work here, but I would like to use some kind of `tidyverse` looping via `purrr` if possible since the dataset is much larger in reality. Any ideas for the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
map_dfc(split.default(df, str_remove(names(df), "_.*")), ~coalesce(!!!.x))
# A tibble: 10 x 2
    ABC1  ABC2
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     4
 2     5     2
 3     3     1
 4     4     1
 5     3     5
 6     5     3
 7     5     2
 8     1     1
 9     2     4
10     4     2
```

Putting it together:

```
df %>%
   split.default(str_replace(names(.), "_.*", "_new")) %>%
   map_dfc(~coalesce(!!!.x))%>%
   cbind(df, .)
   ABC1_old ABC2_old ABC1_adj ABC2_adj ABC1_new ABC2_new
1         1        4       NA       NA        1        4
2         5        2       NA       NA        5        2
3         3        1       NA       NA        3        1
4         4        1       NA       NA        4        1
5         3        5       NA       NA        3        5
6        NA       NA        5        3        5        3
7        NA       NA        5        2        5        2
8        NA       NA        1        1        1        1
9        NA       NA        2        4        2        4
10       NA       NA        4        2        4        2
```

Comment: I see this is coalescing the columns, but is there a way to run an evaluation instead? E.g., if Old is NA, use Adj, otherwise use Old?

Comment: @R.Baratheon that is exactly what coalesce is doing

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c(".value", 'grp'), 
      names_sep = '_', values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-grp, -rn) %>% 
  rename_all(~ str_c(., '_new')) %>% bind_cols(df, .)
#   ABC1_old ABC2_old ABC1_adj ABC2_adj ABC1_new ABC2_new
#1         1        4       NA       NA        1        4
#2         5        2       NA       NA        5        2
#3         3        1       NA       NA        3        1
#4         4        1       NA       NA        4        1
#5         3        5       NA       NA        3        5
#6        NA       NA        5        3        5        3
#7        NA       NA        5        2        5        2
#8        NA       NA        1        1        1        1
#9        NA       NA        2        4        2        4
#10       NA       NA        4        2        4        2
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(ends_with('old'),
    ~ coalesce(., get(str_replace(cur_column(), 
     'old', 'adj'))), .names = '{.col}_new'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a package on github to solve this and similar problems. In this case we could use `dplyover::across2` to apply one (or more) functions to two set of columns, which can be selected with tidyselect. In the `.names` argument we can specify `"{pre}"` to refer to the common prefix of both sets of columns.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover

df %>% 
  mutate(across2(ends_with("_old"),
                 ends_with("_adj"),
                 ~ coalesce(.x, .y),
                 .names = "{pre}_new"))

#>    ABC1_old ABC2_old ABC1_adj ABC2_adj ABC1_new ABC2_new
#> 1         1        4       NA       NA        1        4
#> 2         5        2       NA       NA        5        2
#> 3         3        1       NA       NA        3        1
#> 4         4        1       NA       NA        4        1
#> 5         3        5       NA       NA        3        5
#> 6        NA       NA        5        3        5        3
#> 7        NA       NA        5        2        5        2
#> 8        NA       NA        1        1        1        1
#> 9        NA       NA        2        4        2        4
#> 10       NA       NA        4        2        4        2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Oh the idea behind `across2` sounds interesting. For a moment I couldn't understand how I never noticed that before till I realized you are the author. Congratulations I will check it out.